# Can black holes have colour charge?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement, color-charge

Does the no hair's theorem take into account all the elementary particles and forces, and in particular can a black hole have color charge?

Comment: And https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142551/black-hole-no-hair-theorem and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148374/do-black-holes-have-transient-color-charge

Answer (score 2):

There can be no color charge because
quarks exist only as color neutral combinations .Even quarks emitted as  Hawking radiation would be expected to be color  neutral combinations.

Comment: I was expecting for such answer but let's assume that the strong force have asymptotically free particles

Comment: In a universe without confinement, sure. But note that even net electric charge hasn't been observed for a black hole in nature.

Comment: Using the idea of color charge on a black hole , 3 black holes with different colours could evaporate and lose mass and combine to become a proton. The reverse of this is that a proton with mass added to it could become 3 black holes However a proton with mass added to it becomes a neutron. So black holes having color charge does not seem likely