# Why do physicists believe the "no-hair conjecture" to be true?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

The [no-hair conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) states that a black hole is completely characterized by its mass, electric charge, and angular momentum. Most physicists take it as given. My question is, why?

- It implies the [black hole information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox), which violates time reversibility and quantum mechanics in a way that is some what difficult to reconcile.
- Analogous theorems, such as the four-dimensional equivalent, is outright false, which doesn't lend to the theorem being true.
- We have no evidence for the no-hair conjecture being true as far as I can tell. It would be difficult to find direct evidence until we could observe a black hole closer.

The only thing in favor of the no-hair conjecture that I can see is Steven Hawking proved that some hard to justify assumptions would imply it. Oh, and a lot of people mistake it for a theorem (which it isn't), which could confuse people into thinking it must be true?

Why is the no-hair conjecture taken as given?

Note: The question "[Black hole "no hair" theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142551/black-hole-no-hair-theorem)" only addresses why a black hole must have mass and magnetic hair. It doesn't address why there isn't other types of hair.

Comment: Related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142551/9887

Comment: Why are some voting to close this as opinion based? I am asking what evidence there is for a widely accepted physical law. This doesn't have much to do with opinions.