# Angular momentum of rotating black holes

Tags: black-holes

If a black hole rotates, how does the information about its angular momentum get passed up beyond its event horizon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black hole "no hair" theorem](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142551/)

Comment: By frame dragging and by the shape and size of the event horizon.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same reason as for the effect of mass: angular momentum is conserved and made of the properties of what is going in the BH. See from the exterior, everything seems (radially) frozen on the event horizon, and you should simply consider that this is the stuff causing the various effects you can measure from the exterior.